# How can i change checkout page drop down arrow to plus/minus using opncart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opencart

I want to use plus/minus icon instead of down arrow. I have tried but i don't know when i will have to add minus icon or plus icon. Please guide me Many thanks

[image]

Comment: which version of opencart you are using ?

Comment: @zedBlackbeard I'm using this version `2.1.0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THIS THING MADE ME CRAZY**

Add the following functions in **..\catalog\view\theme\YOURTHEMEFOLDER\template\checkout\checkout.tpl**
or if you have no theme or if your theme has not checkout template, relace the class in **..\catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\checkout.tpl**

```
$('i.fa.fa-caret-down').attr('class','fa fa-minus'); // to replace the firsts elements

$('#accordion').on('click','a.accordion-toggle',function(){
    var el=$('i',this);
    el.hasClass('fa-minus') ? el.attr('class','fa fa-plus') : el.attr('class','fa fa-minus');
    $('a.accordion-toggle i.fa').not(el).attr('class','fa fa-plus');
});
```

Comment: class="fa fa-plus" only show the + sign,  requirement is + and - sign with toggle.

Comment: @zedBlackbeard please, check the last answer I've edited